# Project Item Template: where does Visual Studio specify dependencies?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

as explained here http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/11/05/2556.aspx one can customize project item template.

But at the moment I just try to understand how it works. For example I unzipped the usercontrol file and in usercontrol.vstemplate I cannot see how mycontrol.designer.cs is dependant on mycontrol.cs as this appear in project file as:

```
<DependentUpon>mycontrol.cs</DependentUpon>
```

so any idea ?

Update: Could this dependency not specified somewhere in the project type template ? This would be more clever than relying on the IDE heuristic rule which is rather limited since it can only recognize .Designer.cs and not for example .MyCustom.cs.

usercontrol.vstemplate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name Package="{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}" ID="2295" />
    <Description Package="{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}" ID="2296" />
    <Icon Package="{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}" ID="4532" />
    <TemplateID>Microsoft.CSharp.WindowsFormsUserControl</TemplateID>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>94</SortOrder>
    <RequiredFrameworkVersion>2.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
    <NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>1</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
    <DefaultName>UserControl.cs</DefaultName>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
  <References>
   <Reference>
    <Assembly>System</Assembly>
   </Reference>
   <Reference>
    <Assembly>System.Data</Assembly>
   </Reference>
   <Reference>
    <Assembly>System.Drawing</Assembly>
   </Reference>
   <Reference>
    <Assembly>System.Windows.Forms</Assembly>
   </Reference>
   <Reference>
    <Assembly>System.Xml</Assembly>
   </Reference>
  </References>

    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" SubType="UserControl">UserControl.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true">UserControl.Designer.cs</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For types the IDE knows like Window it figures it out automatically.

But if you want to combine files that aren't known to the designer/use a different naming pattern for the files you have to manually add  tags. I've tried this in a project and I concluded it just wasn't worth the effort, also because the IDE will only automatically rename dependent files it knows of (when you change the file name of the main file).

Comment: Manually adding tag currently that's what I'm doing :(

Comment: Yeah, seemed interesting to me as well. But I rename files quite often (I have one class per file and keep the names the same). I had to unload the project, change references, then load the project each time I refactored a class name. It quickly became too much work just to get a prettier file tree.

Answer (score 2):

The IDE is smart enough to figure this out by itself.  Try this in a sample project: Project + Add New Item, Class, named it Foo.cs.  Repeat, now name it Foo.Designer.cs.  Note how it automatically becomes a sub-item of Foo.cs.  The ".Designer" part of the name matters.

Comment: What if I want .mycustom.cs ? If I can only rely on IDE I'm stuck. Is  there any way to specify with project type template or anything else ?

Comment: Not that I have found so far, but it might be one of those undocumented features